# How to reduce application size

Tags: android

My application currently is over 50MB. I have created directories: drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, where I have duplicate resources that differ in size.

Each of these directories contains over 200 bitmaps, and each one weighs a few dozen kB.

I'm wondering how to reduce application size. Can I reduce the number of resources? Eg into the drawable directory to pack only bitmaps in the highest quality (those from the current directory drawable-xxhdpi) and then only scaled them? I know that as I once tried to do something like this, the app "hangs" me like I tested it on phones with lower densities.

Do you have any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nabin-bhandari suggested, you can split the apk by using the technique in [Build Multiple APKs documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html).

Another way, if you already have the same image for `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, you can try to exclude the `drawable` folder. Then you can try to compress the image using [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) or [pngcrush](https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/). For pngquant, it claims:

> The conversion reduces file sizes significantly (often as much as 70%)

I've tested with the png images in my project, and the image is reduced to about 50 -70%.

Answer (score 1):

You can try building multiple apks according to the device type using `splits` in gradle so that only required resources for that architecture/screen-density are bundled in the apk.

Follow this [tutorial.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html)